# Flutter How to make a class only accessible to another class?

Tags: flutter, json-serialization

I'm using json_serializable package to convert json into object. Below is my json

```
{
    "name": "foo bar",
    "age": 10,
    "favouriteFood": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "food": "banana"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "food": "mango"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is the classes i use

```
@JsonSerializable
class user {
    final String name;
    final int age;
    final List<FavouriteFood> favouriteFood;

    const user({
        required this.name = "",
        required this.age = 0,
        required this.favouriteFood = <FavouriteFood>[],
    });
}

@JsonSerializable
class FavouriteFood {
    final int id;
    final String food;

    const FavouriteFood({
        required this.id = 0,
        required this.food = "",
    });
}
```

My problem is, now when i work on other json, *FavouriteFood class* will be shown as suggestion, which is kind of annoying, and i have alot of json to work with, so it bugs me when unused classes show up since most of this classes i only use once

Comment: wdym shown as suggestion?

Comment: how about make it `nullable`.  `final List<FavouriteFood>? favouriteFood` and now you can remove the `required` from `this.favoritefood`

Comment: Rename `FavouriteFood` to `_FavouriteFood` to make it private and then put it in the same file as the `user` class.  Note, however, that doing so would prevent documentation from being generated for `_FavouriteFood` and its members, but that's probably okay if these classes are meant for only your own internal use.

Comment: @pmatatias I'm pretty sure that OP is asking for `FavouriteFood` to not appear in some list of suggested types from their IDE.  That would have nothing to do with the `user` constructor.

Comment:        